# Node packaged dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have a node.js project that uses a dependency which I have listed in the package.json. It all works fine with the dependency however I want to be able to ship my project without people having to download the dependencies. How can I copy the dependency into my project and still use it with `require('')` in my project files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depend on your delivery flow.  *(In what environment, what kind of application, what tools, how and where will you deliver, ...)*

If the dependency is present in your `package.json`  `dependencies`, then you can retrieve it by doing `npm install --production` and use `require('lib');` within your source code as usual.

It is also possible to set your environment `NODE_ENV=production` and just run `npm install`.

If you can't run `npm`, I would suggest you to include the `node_modules` in your distributed package.

### Update

After chatting with your, it appear that the dependency is probably not installed with `npm`.

It is hooked in a system that can use git repository to install plugins.

Because you use a git repository for hosting your module, you should be able to keep `node_modules` into `.gitignore` when you install the module with `npm install git+https://github.com/namespace/repo.git`, it will installed automatically becauuse of `npm install` reading the `package.json`.

If your client does not rely on npm, then you'r only option is to keep `node_modules` on your github repo.

In this case your import should look like:

```
require('./node_modules/module-a');
```

Maybe there is a third option, check with your client software if it can install from npm registry, if this is the case, then you should be able to ignore `node_modules` from the repo, and if it can't then it means you can't use github repository for npm installation, instead use a real npm registry like https://registry.npmjs.com or host your own one with https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio

Comment: I have tried this and not been successful. It just packages stuff into node-modules as normal. How can I at least make node-modules smaller for production? But ideally I want the used repos in the top directory

Comment: Could you describe with more details what you are trying to achieve. Because I have no clue about your project and what you are asking (again) is what I just answered. This would help guide you in the right direction.

Comment: My project is at https://github.com/615283/roon-discord-rp. As you can see, for now I have ungitignored the required dependency. However I want to be able to have it out of the node modules folder but still use require(). I also only want that dependency there.

Comment: I see. The fact that it is in `node_modules` is not an issue by node, by default, it look in `node_modules` so you should NOT move your dependency. Also, I must ask you how do you use your module. Because if you publish it on npm by running `npm publish`, then it will pack everything up including your node modules. You don't need to have your `node_modules` folder on github, but you need it when you create the archive.

Comment: Can I change the look locations?

Comment: If you want to test before publishing, you can run `npm pack` after running `npm install` within your project. this will create an archive `.tar.gz`, you can then install the archive anywhere where you need it (even globally with `-g`) using `npm install <archive>` . After publishin on npm with `npm publish`, you can run `npm install <myPackage>`, if you install from Github, then you need to have the `node_modules` on your repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186602/discussion-between-615283-and-dimitri-kopriwa).